# Cant pass input_shape to LSTM layer in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a numpy array `X_train` of shape `(number of samples, timestep , number of features)` =`(1198,60,1)`I am trying to create an LSTM layer at the begining of my model :

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
```

But this gives me the error :

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_8/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

However, when I remove the input_shape argument everything works fine. So this means that I dont need to specify the input_shape ?